# Liquibase Hibernate diff exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am getting the following exception when trying to run a simple diff between an empty database and my hibernate entities. The exception seems to indicate that it cannot fetch catalognames. I am using a myqsl DB which is currently empty (no tables). My goal is to use the entities in my code to create the changelog. 
The entities are part of a spring-boot app.

Here are the liquibase properties

```
    referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.lowes.order.domain.pojos?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
    url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username=root
    password=password
    promptOnNonLocalDatabase=false
    verbose=true
    driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml
    changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-changeLog.xml
    diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog.xml
    defaultSchemaName=test
    referenceDefaultSchemaName=test
    defaultCatalogName=test
    referenceDefaultCatalogName=test
```

Here is the exception when I run mvn liquibase:diff -X

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:398)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:233)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:210)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:182)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:13)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:231)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:210)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:182)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseCatalogNames (CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:82)*
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject (CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:41)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot (JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:60)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot (SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include (DatabaseSnapshot.java:246)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init (DatabaseSnapshot.java:75)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init> (DatabaseSnapshot.java:53)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init> (JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:28)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot (SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:150)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot (SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:139)
    at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot (DiffCommand.java:219)
    at liquibase.command.DiffCommand.createDiffResult (DiffCommand.java:141)
    at liquibase.command.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run (DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:51)
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:8)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:231)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:210)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:182)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: Try using another liquibase version?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same needs as you, and experience the same issue. Liquibase-hibernate extension must match the right version of liquibase-plugin. Follows are my maven configuration for solution:

````xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
 ```        <propertyFile>${basedir}/target/classes/db/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
````